# React GUI on Kafka

Tags: reactjs, apache-kafka, react-redux

I’m trying to build a real time GUI in React which listens to Kafka.  I had a few questions on best practices.

My architecture is Kafka > Websocket Server > React App

Say I have three events on my orders topic:

```
Order ( Value = 1 )
Order ( Value = 2 )
Order ( Value = 3 )
```

And on my web app I want to show a table of the 2 highest value orders, sorted by value.

Is the React state the best place to do this?  It feels quite database like when we have the power of Kafka?

Maybe I do this in the node websocket server where on each order event I reconsider the stream from start to select the two largest orders and rewrite through the websocket?

Maybe I do this with KSQL.  I don’t think it’s possible to execute an order by even on a table.  You can only lookup by ID.

Any thoughts please?

Comment: I suggest you do the sorting on the backend and then send the result to react.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd build a KTable that maintains the state for Top-N entries. Then your React app would use Interactive Query rather than websocket to fetch all key-value pairs and sort client side. Or you can implement the sorting server-side within a custom Serde.